# Suggestions on why this linq ef core query wont execute

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Good morning,

I have the following query in EF Core which works as required if I do **not** add into the the where clause a condition for the createdtimestamp.  If I add other conditions clauses to filter down the data as shown below the query **will** execute without issue.

```
            var q = (
                from trckhead in DbContext.TrackingBatchHeader
                from userdets in DbContext.UserDetails
                    .Where(u => u.UserId == trckhead.ClosedByUserId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from trckkeys in DbContext.TrackingBatchesItemKey
                    .Where(t => t.TrackingNo == trckhead.TrackingNo).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from trcklink1 in DbContext.TrackingBatchesLink
                    .Where(x => x.TrackingNo == trckhead.TrackingNo && x.TrackingType == "I").DefaultIfEmpty()
                from trcklink2 in DbContext.TrackingBatchesLink
                    .Where(x => x.TrackingNo == trckhead.TrackingNo && x.TrackingType == "T").DefaultIfEmpty()
                join trckref in DbContext.TrackingBatchesReference on trckhead.TrackingBatchType equals trckref
                    .TrackingBatchType
                join mthsite in DbContext.SiteDetail on trckhead.SiteCode equals mthsite.SiteCode
                join userdets2 in DbContext.UserDetails on trckhead.CreatedByUserId equals userdets2.UserId
                where
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchRequest.Status) || trckhead.Status == searchRequest.Status) &&      
                trckhead.CreatedTimestamp >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-11)
                select new TrackingBatchSearchResultDto
                {
                    TrackingBatchId = trckhead.TrackingNo,
                    SiteCode = trckhead.SiteCode,
                    TrackingBatchType = trckhead.TrackingBatchType,
                    Status = trckhead.Status,
                    Created = trckhead.CreatedTimestamp,
                    CreatedById = trckhead.CreatedByUserId,
                    ClosedById = trckhead.ClosedByUserId,
                    UserDescription = trckhead.UsersDescription,
                    TrackingBatchDescription = trckref.TrackingBatchTypeDescription,
                    SiteName = mthsite.Title,
                    CreatedByName = userdets2.FullUserName ?? string.Empty,
                    ClosedByName = userdets.FullUserName ?? string.Empty,
                    Link1 = trcklink1.TrackingData ?? string.Empty,
                    Link2 = trcklink2.TrackingData ?? string.Empty
                }).Distinct();

            return await q.ToListAsync();
```

If I keep the date clause in the query the exception that is raised shows the following.  I would have thought the server evaluation wouldnt be happy if I was passing a function into the query but checking against a simple date has thrown me.  I could filter the results by date after obtaining the whole data set but the number of records returned can be massive so I would rather filter it down from a database query.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<TrackingBatchHeader>
    .SelectMany(
        source: t => DbSet<UserDetail>
            .Where(u => u.UserId == t.ClosedByUserId)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        collectionSelector: (t, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<TrackingBatchHeader, UserDetail>(
            Outer = t, 
            Inner = c
        ))
    .SelectMany(
        source: ti => DbSet<TrackingBatchesItemKey>
            .Where(t0 => t0.TrackingNo == ti.Outer.TrackingNo)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        collectionSelector: (ti, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TrackingBatchHeader, UserDetail>, TrackingBatchesItemKey>(
            Outer = ti, 
            Inner = c
        ))
    .SelectMany(
        source: ti0 => DbSet<TrackingBatchesLink>
            .Where(t1 => t1.TrackingNo == ti0.Outer.Outer.TrackingNo && t1.TrackingType == "I")
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        collectionSelector: (ti0, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TrackingBatchHeader, UserDetail>, TrackingBatchesItemKey>, TrackingBatchesLink>(
            Outer = ti0, 
            Inner = c
        ))
    .SelectMany(
        source: ti1 => DbSet<TrackingBatchesLink>
            .Where(t2 => t2.TrackingNo == ti1.Outer.Outer.Outer.TrackingNo && t2.TrackingType == "T")
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        collectionSelector: (ti1, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TrackingBatchHeader, UserDetail>, TrackingBatchesItemKey>, TrackingBatchesLink>, TrackingBatchesLink>(
            Outer = ti1, 
            Inner = c
        ))
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<TrackingBatchesReference>, 
        inner: ti2 => ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.TrackingBatchType, 
        outerKeySelector: t3 => t3.TrackingBatchType, 
        innerKeySelector: (ti2, t3) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TrackingBatchHeader, UserDetail>, TrackingBatchesItemKey>, TrackingBatchesLink>, TrackingBatchesLink>, TrackingBatchesReference>(
            Outer = ti2, 
            Inner = t3
        ))
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<SiteDetail>, 
        inner: ti3 => ti3.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.SiteCode, 
        outerKeySelector: s => s.SiteCode, 
        innerKeySelector: (ti3, s) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TrackingBatchHeader, UserDetail>, TrackingBatchesItemKey>, TrackingBatchesLink>, TrackingBatchesLink>, TrackingBatchesReference>, SiteDetail>(
            Outer = ti3, 
            Inner = s
        ))
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<UserDetail>, 
        inner: ti4 => ti4.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.CreatedByUserId, 
        outerKeySelector: u0 => u0.UserId, 
        innerKeySelector: (ti4, u0) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TrackingBatchHeader, UserDetail>, TrackingBatchesItemKey>, TrackingBatchesLink>, TrackingBatchesLink>, TrackingBatchesReference>, SiteDetail>, UserDetail>(
            Outer = ti4, 
            Inner = u0
        ))
    .Where(ti5 => ti5.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.CreatedTimestamp >= (Nullable<DateTime>)DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-11))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Don't write such queries. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL and EF Core isn't a data access library. DbContext isn't a model of the database. EF Core is an Object-to-Relational-Mapper. SQL queries will be generated by EF Core based on relations between objects. There shouldn't be any reason for `JOIN` in a LINQ query. As for the `Where` clause, there's no need for catch-all tricks like `string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchRequest.Status)`. You can add filters conditionally, eg `if (status!=null){ query=query.Where(t=>t.Status == status);}`.

Comment: If your DbContext and entities were properly configured you wouldn't need any of those joins. If you use simple object access notation in the `Select()` clause LINQ would translate it to the necessary JOINs and add the necessary fields in the `SELECT` clause

Comment: The exception doesn't match the query you posted.  Can you simplify the query and post the actual query and exception?

Comment: @K4E you should. Because *that's* what's needed to simplify the query and eliminate code that may be causing the problem. After that, the catch-all clause is another thing that can cause problems. There's no way that `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` can be translated to SQL. There's no such function. It doesn't even have to be in the query since all it does is disable the next clause. You can chain `.Where()` calls and the result is equivalent to `AND`. That's why using `if(status==null){ q=q.Where(...);}` can be used to add filters conditionally

Comment: @K4E Please ignore general comments as they are irrelevant to the issue. What EF Core version are you using? Because latest EFC 5 / 6 show better error messages in such situations containing more hints what could be causing it.  From what I see, the problem is either `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-11)` which I'm pretty sure is translatable, or most likely `CreatedTimestamp` property of the entity class in unmapped (via `[NotMapped]` or `.Ignore`).

Comment: Thanks for the comments I will take all on board and report back to the team.  I did make  a mistake in posting the code the query should have had DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-11) in it not from the searchrequest.

Answer (score 2):

Plainly speaking, neglecting either establish navigation properties for the relationships between entities and instead using manual outer joins using "from" plus then adding the ultimate insult to poorly formed queries with `Distinct` is trying to use EF like a hammer to pound a square peg through a round hole.

With proper relationships, that query should be trivial.

Your datetime condition error message does not match your query.

** Edit: Removed details on Date comparison - This does not appear to be directly related as I did verify that the Nullable Date/DateTime comparisons  do work with `.AddMonth()` in EF Core.

Expanding out conditional logic can help simplify the queries being executed.

For example:

```
var query = (/*build your base query*/);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchRequest.Status))
    query = query.Where(x => x.Status == searchRequest.Status);
if (searchRequest.DateFrom.HasValue)
{
   var fromDate = searchRequest.DateFrom.Value.AddMonths(-11);
   query = query.Where(x => x.CreatedTimestamp >= fromDate);
}

var results = query.Select(...).Distinct().ToList();
```

EF can perform some magic to build queries provided you give it enough information to do it properly. Seeing it build something like `ti5.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.CreatedTimestamp` should be sending off alarm bells. There may be something deep in your query lurking that is tripping a Client-side evaluation, or it is simply a case that a combination of joins and such has tipped over a complexity limit or exposed a bug in EF Core. The starting point would be to look to simplify that query expression by leveraging navigation properties rather than joins, and externalizing the conditional logic where you can.

If you have no recourse but to try and query across relationships that you are not prepared to map out properly with navigation properties, I would recommend exploring building your query in SQL as a Stored Procedure and then defining an Entity that can map to the resulting record from that Sproc.

Comment: EF Core is quite different from EF6 your habits coming from. While I also prefer/recommend navigation properties over manual joins, I would never suggest going to SP/raw SQL for a simple query with joins. Other things you mentioned also do not apply to EFC - conditional `Where` is not mandatory since EFC eliminates constant predicates (as you can see, there is no `searchRequest.Status` condition in the error expression). Also according to the error they are using `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-11)` which is perfectly translatable. So you have no idea what's the concrete problem and just guessing.

Comment: I dislike the way EF Core throws "could not be translated" when an expression visitor fails to replace an expression. While this might be easier for the EF Core team to write, it provides no clue as to why the failure occurred. You might be right about the date expression, you might not.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I will take all on board and report back to the team.  I did make  a mistake in posting the code the query should have had DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-11) in it not from the searchrequest.

Comment: I have updated the answer after verifying that the DateTime operations and comparisons against a null-able Date or DateTime property are probably not directly responsible, though it is curious that removal of that condition seems to allow the query to run. I did verify the operations do work with EF Core 3.1 and 5. The solution will likely involve drastically simplifying the query, if not solving some form of complexity issue, but reducing the surface area to look for a potential problem.